# recover flash drive (no need to recover files)

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive

I was writing a file of 4GB on my flash drive. The process made the whole system slow so I restarted system and found that the drive works no longer.

#### I Don't need to recover it's contents I only want to make it working once more

wnen Gparted is first executed it shows dialog box with

```
input/output error during read on /dev/sdd
```

I click on ignore. And when I click On information  it shows following

```
Model:    JetFlash Transcend 16GB
Size:     14.71 GiB
Path:     /dev/sdd

Partitioin Table :unrecognized
Heads:            255
Sectors :          63
...
```

When I try to create new partitioin table it again alerts `input/output error during read on /dev/sdd`

When The drive is inserted in usb port the system log is:

```
Feb  8 00:41:47 Bhattarai kernel: [ 1579.729681] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Feb  8 00:41:47 Computer kernel: [ 1579.731114] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Device not ready
Feb  8 00:41:47 Computer kernel: [ 1579.731117] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd]  
Feb  8 00:41:47 Computer kernel: [ 1579.731118] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Feb  8 00:41:47 Computer kernel: [ 1579.731120] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd]  
Feb  8 00:41:47 Computer kernel: [ 1579.731122] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Feb  8 00:41:47 Computer kernel: [ 1579.731124] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd]  
Feb  8 00:41:47 Computer kernel: [ 1579.731127] Add. Sense: Medium not present
Feb  8 00:41:47 Computer kernel: [ 1579.731129] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: 
Feb  8 00:41:47 Computer kernel: [ 1579.731130] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
```

I tried `mktable` form `sudo parted /dev/sdd` I again get `Input/Output error while writing on /dev/sdd`

Comment: Try `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd`. Maybe you have to replace it...

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd` again gives input/output error on /dev/sdd

Comment: The drive had two partitions: ext for bootabe ubuntu and ntfs for other data,which I made 2 hours before and was working perfectly fine. And when i was copying files to ntfs partitoin,this happened.does making partition have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If even

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd
```

is giving you an I/O error, your USB stick is broken: throw it away and buy a new one.

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news. **:-(**

Comment: Then why does gparted shows it's name `JetFlash Transcend 16 GB` and it's size `14.71 GB`?

Comment: Because the master boot record is still readable...  The unrecoverable error is after that.  If you have no money to buy a new one, leave me a comment and you *might be able* to recover it, but in my experience you'll end up losing data as the problem is only going to get worse and worse.